# Role Assignment "New-AzRoleAssignment" for Azure Blob Storage is failing using powershell script

Tags: azure-devops, azure-blob-storage

Below is my scenario for which I have created a powershell task in Azure DevOps pipeline

Scenario= I am trying to query the files from ADLS blob storage in azure synapse workspace. To do this I need to grant "Storage Blob Data Reader" Role to my ADLS blob storage to run/query the data(csv/parquet) files in synapse Workspace. I have run the below script in power shell task in azure Devops pipeline and getting below error.

Script=

> New-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectID "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" `-RoleDefinitionName "Storage Blob DataReader"`
> -Scope "/subscriptions/AAAAA/resourceGroups/BBBBBB/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/XXXXXXXX"

I have passed Object ID (tried both App ID, Object ID of the service principal ),Subscription id, resource group name and storage account.

Error=

> operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden' . Power shell
> exited with code '1'

PFA screenshot. I am not really sure what I am missing here. Please share your valuable suggestions.

[image: DevOps Script]
[image: Error]

Comment: What's the RBAC role assigned to the Service Principal executing this script?

Comment: @GauravMantri..hi, I am not sure how to check this. AFAIK, there are other similar scripts using service Principal is working fine.

Comment: @sac Are you using a service principal different from the one used in DevOps task?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think I needs to explain how it works:

Everything you do from the DevOps pipeline side are based on service principal on the Azure Portal.

From the description, it seems you are using the Azure PowerShell? If so, you can find the 'Azure Subscription' of this task in this place of your DevOps project(In fact, it is related to register app of AAD on Azure Portal):

[image]

After that, everything is only related to the AAD app on Azure Portal side, you need to make sure it has required permission. I suggest you to take a look of this:

[New-AzRoleAssignment HTTP 403 error when running as Service Principal](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/16414)